# Binding Key or Routing Key

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a question regarding routing keys versus binding keys in RabbitMQ. As I understand it, a producer sends a message to an exchange with a **routing key**. The queue is bound to the exchange with a **binding key**. However, I came across this explanation of default exchange keys:

> Every queue is automatically bound to the Default Exchange with a routing key which is the same as the queue name.

Should this statement say "binding key" instead of "routing key"? Or are the terms basically equivalent?

To me, every queue is bound to the default exchange with a binding key equal to the queue name means that internally this is the case:

```
channel.queueBind(queueName, "", queueName);
```

Is this correct? Every queue is bound to the default exchange with a binding key same as the queue name. Since the default exchange is nothing but a direct exchange with no name, it will match the routing key with the binding key of the queue and  route it if they are equal. Am I correct in my understanding? The two terms "binding key" and "routing key" are used a little confusingly.

Answer (score 12):

In a nutshell:

- **routing keys** are on **messages**,
- **binding keys** are on **routes (bindings)**,
- Exchanges compare a message's *routing key* to each route's *binding key* to determine if the message should be sent to the queue on that route.

**It's confusing because RabbitMQ documentation and source code use *both terms* when referring to the binding key.**

For example, the `IModel.queueBind()` parameter named `routingKey` is where you specify the binding key:

```
void QueueBind(string queue, string exchange, string routingKey, IDictionary<string, object> arguments);
```

In the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html), it says:

> Bindings can take an extra `routingKey` parameter. To avoid the
> confusion with a `BasicPublish` parameter we're going to call it a
> `binding key`.

**So while they are indeed distinct, sometimes "routing key" is used when referring to a binding key**, due to their close relationship.

Comment: In the AMQP 0.9.1 specification, the key used for publishing a message and for binding a queue are both called a "routing key". But, I think because they are different concepts (e.g. in a topic exchange, the binding key is used for wildcard matching), they really SHOULD be called by different names. So it seems wise to deviate from AMQP spec and call them routing key and binding key anyway.

Answer (score 9):

The binding-key is used with the queue. It is the key with which the queue is registered in the exchange.

The routing-key is used with the message. It is the key which will decide which queue(s) does this message should be routed to. Messages can have other type of identifiers for routing, like matchers in Topic Exchange.

> Every queue is automatically bound to the default exchange with a routing key which is the same as the queue name.

Now, the routing-key and binding-key is not the same concept. 
But, here, in the case of Default Exchange, the binding key will be the same  as the name of the queue. So, the messages will also have the same routing-key as the Queue name.

So,

> channel.queueBind(queueName, "", queueName);

is not exactly the correct thing to do. However, it depends on the type of the exchange, how the queue will be bound to the exchange. In the case of default exchange, it is bind with the name of the queue, so it will be done by the RabbitMQ.